# Splitting a .dat file in Python to plot

Tags: python, plot, split

I have a .dat file that I would like to plot some of the data within the file. I removed the first couple rows of the file using `nom1 = open('file1.dat','rb').readlines()[3:]`

The .dat file looks something like this after rows removed :

```
Flow  2012  9 22 24  0  230.0000      354.0856
Flow  2012  9 23 24  0  231.0000      353.0887
Flow  2012  9 24 24  0  236.0000      357.0877
Flow  2012  9 25 24  0  235.0000      358.0837
```

In total there should be 8 columns but it is reading each line as a large set of letters and numbers. I would like to plot the time, which is in "columns" 2,3,and 4 (example 2012/9/22), against columns 7 and 8. I thought about using split function `nom2=nom1.split()`but I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`. The next thought was to try and use delineate by white space but had no real good idea on how to go about it. If there is a faster and more efficient way going about this please let me know. Also, please let me know if I am being too vague.

Thanks

Comment: you need to iterate over the items present inside the list and then do the split for each item.

Comment: nom1.split("\n").split() will give you a 2d array in the form you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> file = open(r"class X.txt")
>>> type(file.readlines())
<class 'list'>
```

So readlines returns a list? So it's obvious that doing a slicing notation on it will jsut skip the first 3 items in the list. But what exactly is in that list?

```
>>> for line in file.readlines():
    print(type(line))   
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

So each line is read in as an individual string! That means that `[3:]` will skip fist 3 lines in the file, not columns. Ok, but how can we get the actual columns?

```
>>> for line in file.readlines():
    print(line.split())  
['Flow', '2012', '9', '22', '24', '0', '230.0000', '354.0856']
['Flow', '2012', '9', '23', '24', '0', '231.0000', '353.0887']
```

Ok, getting there, we just split each individual string (row) into multiple strings stored in a list. Now we can skip the first 3 columns by doing `[3:]`. We need somewhere to save that. How about a list where each element is a list of the columns we need?

```
>>> interesting = []
>>> for line in file.readlines():
    interesting.append(line.split()[3:])
>>> interesting
[['22', '24', '0', '230.0000', '354.0856'], ['23', '24', '0', '231.0000', '353.0887'], ['24', '24', '0', '236.0000', '357.0877'], ['25', '24', '0', '235.0000', '358.0837']]
>>> interesting[0]
['22', '24', '0', '230.0000', '354.0856']
```

and voilá there we go. Think about this a bit, hopefully it should make itself perfectly clear.

Comment: If I wanted to write "interesting" to a new .txt file would I just put something like:
newtxt = open("newfile", 'wb') 
newtxt.write(interesting)

Comment: @BobBlacklock yes, but perhaps you are better off with just `w` flag, since `wb` means "write bytes" while "w" will mostly likely default to ASCII char.

Comment: @BobBlacklock Oh sorry, I miss-read, you will again have to iterate through `interesting` to write each member, because otherwise you'll just write down an unusable instance of `interesting`

Answer (score 0):

read in csv file first, then split.

```
file = pd.read_csv('path/file.dat',header = None)
```